# Thread-cached object referencing

Tags: c++, c, memory

I need to create a sort of a shared object (for whatever reason). It's not limited to the single-threaded usage. Generally in such cases interlocked operations are the way to go (such as `InterlockedIncrement` and `InterlockedDecrement` on Win32).

Whereas the object reference counting should work correctly in any scenario, I'd like to optimize it for single-threaded usage. Interlocked operations are very much heavier than the standard arithmetic ones. From my measurements an interlocked operation (issuing full memory barrier) takes about 40 CPU cycles on my "typical" CPU, whereas standard arithmetic ones are below any measurement accuracy (thanks to CPU cache).

There's a similar technique when it comes to the memory allocation. There are heap implementations, such as "TCMalloc", that consist of a centralized memory partitioning mechanism, guarded by the appropriate synchronization objects, plus per-thread **caching**. In the most common scenario the memory allocated/freed on per-thread cache, which doesn't involve any interlocked operations at all, plus CPU cache is utilized with high probability.

Hence I though about a possibility to do something similar for reference-supporting objects. Any ideas how to achieve this? Raw ideas are also welcome.

It's ok in my scenario to delay the actual object destruction for some time, if this improves the performance.

Comment: How about a flag that would be set for multithread access. When a thread is created, it will flag (or increase that flag). If the flag is 1, you could test it with an "if" and increment as appropriate.

Comment: Are you trying to optimize the AddRef and Release operations?  Or the memory allocations (and deallocations)? Are you suggesting that all these operations on the objects will be on the same thread?

Comment: I don't get the question.  Per thread caching uses thread local storage.

Comment: @axeoth: The application is multi-threaded, there're constantly many thread. However a specific instance of an object will most probably be used in a single thread only. The object doesn't know from the beginning how it will be used.

Comment: @selbie: Yes, I'm trying to optimize `AddRef` and `Release`. Most, but not necessarily all, operations are done in the same thread.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't bother. I just ran this benchmark:

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define SIZE 1000000

static __inline__ unsigned long long rdtsc(void)
{
    unsigned hi, lo;
    __asm__ __volatile__ ("rdtsc" : "=a"(lo), "=d"(hi));
    return ( (unsigned long long)lo)|( ((unsigned long long)hi)<<32 );
}


void print_avg(const char *str, const int *diff, int size)
{
    int i;
    long sum = 0;
    int max = -1, min = 10000;
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
    int t = diff[i];
    sum += t;
    if (t > max) max = t;
    if (t < min) min = t;
    }

    printf("%s average =%f clocks, max =%d, min =%d\n", str, (double)sum / size, max, min);
}



int main()
{
    unsigned long long a, b;
    int diff[SIZE];
    int value = 0;
    int i;


    for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
    a = rdtsc();

    __sync_fetch_and_add(&value, 2);
    b = rdtsc();

    diff[i] = (int)(b - a);
    }

    print_avg("Locked", diff, SIZE);

    for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
    a = rdtsc();
        value += 2;
    b = rdtsc();
    diff[i] = (int)(b - a);
    }
    print_avg("Not locked", diff, SIZE);

    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with gcc -O2 it gives the following results:

```
Locked average =105.672402 clocks, max =38756, min =86  
Not locked average =80.540389 clocks, max =23433, min =73
```

I ran it several times, and the results are very similar each time. Please ignore the big numbers for max - that's when the processor takes an interrupt or something - it came from some code I wrote for a different purpose, and I just recycled that for this test. This small difference should apply on all modern processors (Intel iCore and AMD Athlon64 and those sort of generations)

Unless for some reason your compiler doesn't inline InterlockedIncrement, adding an if-statement on your code will most likely cost at least 5 cycles, so you are saving at most 10 cycles. Hopefully you are doing something else than incrementing and decrementing the reference counters.

Edit: Adding a memory barrier doesn't make a big difference either - about 10 cycles.

Admittedly, if I add ten adds in the second loop, it makes about five clock cycles to the each loop (so half a clock per add, on average), where as the locked add takes about 20 clocks per add. It's still not worth adding an if-statement, in my opinion. But if you fancy adding "if (nr_threads == 1) a = a + 1; else a = __sync_fetch_and_add(a, 1);", [or whatever it takes to do what you need] I'm not going to stop you. But make sure that you benchmark your entire application and make sure it makes more than 1% improvement - I doubt it. Please do come back and tell us what the difference is. My added if-statement in the "deallocate page-table entries" for the Linux kernel made it 2-5% slower, so wasn't worth it. But if you find that in your code, it's worth it, be my guest. I'm speaking from experience, and I have the numbers to show it, but if you feel like trying for yourself, sure why not.

Comment: Thanks very much for the effort, you definitely deserve the upvote :). However there **is** a reason to bother. You measure the performance of `+=` with `rdtsc` plus some surrounding code generated by the compiler (such as registers `push/pop`) - this is simply insane!

Comment: Incrementing the value of a register is the very base CPU operation. I'm sure a typical modern CPU can do several such operations in a single cycle! Plus `__sync_fetch_and_add` probably invalidates the CPU cache for `value`, hence every consequent `+=` leads to the memory access. That's why you got such a minor difference. Consider rewriting your test such that you do dozens of consequent `+=` vs dozens of consequent `__sync_fetch_and_add` in a single test cycle (i.e. between `rdtsc`). I bet you'll see a huge difference.

Comment: I disagree on two accounts:
1. It is a valid test. It may not test exactly your circumstances, but it clearly shows that the CPU is not taking hundreds of cycles to perform a locked add (I have recently been working on something that does something similar for the Linux kernel, where I was trying to determine if a locked xchg could be done more clever with some other operation, hence I already had some code for this). 
Second point in next comment.

Comment: 2. No it doesn't flush the CPU cache on the processor running the add operation. It flushes [specifically, it forces an invalidate on the cache of the other cores/cpus] the caches on OTHER cpu's that may be sharing that data. As long as the cache isn't dirty on the other CPU, it will not take much time - and it would only be dirty if another CPU is touching the same memory, which would be multithreading [or your code is switching between one CPU and another]. I added the memory barrier to make sure the CPU would not continue executing other instructions, and it added 10 cycles, give or take.

Comment: With 10 __sync_fetch_and_add, the time taken for each loop is 300 clocks, so essentially about two dozen cycles per locked add (taking into account that rdtsc takes some 30-40 cycles). I also modified it so that it updates different variables, and adding a memory barrier at the half-way point. It makes very little difference.

Comment: So your "valid" test actually tests some circumstances that are "not exactly mine". Alright, it may have some academic value, but I'm talking about practical problem, in the context of my specific circumstances. Anyway, regardless to the situation, it's not a correct approach to measure something whereas your "measurement tool" imposes a comparable load, whereas this is avoidable (at least by doing many such small operations in a cycle).

Comment: Plus I've never said interlocked operations take "hunders of CPU cycles". They take tens (on a typical CPU). About other your notes. Actually I'm not certain about exact memory fences imposed by `__sync_fetch_and_add`, maybe you're right. If so - what could be the explanation of `+=` taking tens of CPU cycles? I can easily write you a test with a simple `+=` increments, and demonstrate you this doesn't take more than 1 cycle. Also, I'm surprised by your claim that `rdtsc` takes "some 30-40 cycles". Are you sure? This also doesn't make much sense, it's a trivial operation.

Comment: I have added another comment in my answer, as the comment became too long.

Comment: Alright, this makes sense. I'll add the "fancy `if` " to see if there's any measurable difference at all, before digging any further. Thank you very much for the effort. Too bad I can only upvote your answer once.